# Ionic Photo Viewer doesn't work on ios

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native, photoviewer

I'm using Ionic Photo Viewer to show images in full screen. My HTML is:-

```
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide col-12 *ngFor="let image of businessImages | async">
     <div class="main-slider-image" [defaultImage]="'assets/imgs/default_image_slider.png'" [lazyLoad]="image.thumb400Url" [offset]="100" (click)="openImage(image.originalUrl)">
     </div>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

On TypeScript:-

```
openImage(url) {
    this.photoViewer.show(url, "", { share: false });
}
```

On Android is working like this:-

[Click here to see Android version](https://youtu.be/DekdiIpXmfQ)

On the other hand, on the iPhone is working like this:-

[Click here to see iPhone version](https://youtu.be/QNYh2bziZJ0)

On the iPhone, the photo viewer doesn't open the photo. I've tried:-

```
openImage(url) {
    this.photoViewer.show(url);
}
```

But this also didn't work. If you've any idea how to solve this issue please share. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This issue is really crazy and had to spend lots of time to figure out the solutions. The solutions is all the parameters in the 'options' variable are required.

Follow this:

```
const options = {
    share: true, // default is false
    closeButton: true, // default is true
    copyToReference: true, // default is false
    headers: "",  // If it is not provided, it will trigger an exception
    piccasoOptions: { } // If it is not provided, it will trigger an exception
};

this.photoViewer.show(url, "", options);
```

Answer (score 0):

At least I had to revert to 1.1.11 (found from NPM) to show IOS properly. For Android, latest version seemed to work.

Share did not seem to work for IOS in 1.1.11. In Android latest photo-viewer plugin it seemed to work. So now I have:

```
  private viewPhoto(url: string): void {
    if (url && url != 'assets/images/profile.png') {
      this.photoViewer.show(url, '', { share: this.platform.is('android') });
    }
  }
```

And.. I think the correct place to discuss these is https://github.com/sarriaroman/photoviewer/issues.

And another thing, I'm considering to use another plugin, https://github.com/Riron/ionic-img-viewer. Some of the photoviewer issues had a link to this but haven't tried it yet.

Comment: That second plugin is not supporting Ionic 4 though ATM

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, and im solve with this

```
ionic cordova plugin rm com-sarriaroman-photoviewer
ionic cordova plugin add com-sarriaroman-photoviewer@1.1.18
npm install --save @ionic-native/photo-viewer
```

on your function, if device using ios, decodeURIComponent was the answer

```
  showImage(url,title) {
    var options = {
      share: true, // default is false
      closeButton: true, // iOS only: default is true
      copyToReference: true // iOS only: default is false
    };

    if (this.platform.is("ios")) {
      url = decodeURIComponent(url);
    }

    this.photoViewer.show(url, title, options);
  }
```

Comment: Had to use 1.1.11 instead, 1.1.18 was completely broken for me

Answer (score 0):

For IOS, use **[FileOpen](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/file-opener/)** native library instead of **PhotoViwer**